# Android SDK folder structure

Tags: android

Is there a reference like this (http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html) that explains the folders inside the main Android SDK folder?

---

Based on the response I've got so far, I think I need to clarify further what I'm looking for.

I wanted to know the basis for the SDK to be divided into these folders (screenshot below). For e.g. something similar to the following excerpt in the 'SDK Readme.txt'

"Platform-tools contains build tools that are periodically updated to support new features in the Android platform (which is why they are separate from basic SDK tools), including adb, dexdump, and others."

[image: Contents of android-sdk folder]

I did put copy the android-sdk folder at a location separate from IDEs so that it can be shared.

Comment: // suggestion **keep android SDK folder out side of Android-studio**

Answer (score 0):

It's not a guaranteed standard, but the folders have been consistent for many years now. Here are the core basics, see the links for more info:

```
 # platform-tools: Updated each AOSP version; always backwards compatible
 # tools/bin: Platform-independent tools to help building/using android
 #            eg lint, sdkmanager, monkeyrunner
 # build-tools/<version>: Compilation tools, required to build.
 #            AOSP version specific, typically used by AS directly
```

See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/
https://www.programering.com/a/MDMyMzNwATk.html

Answer (score -3):

No, this is proprietary project from Google, so they don't need to follow any standard.